# On restart, how to have Mac OS X reopen windows in their original space?

Tags: macos, osx-spaces

Right now when I restart my Mac and have it reopen the windows automatically upon login, they all load in a single space - the first one. Originally however, before the restart, these windows were spread out across my spaces. Is there a way to have OS X reopen the old windows in their original, correct space?

Comment: Related to your other question? But afaik, an app should open in its assigned space, assuming it has one, unless you had multiple windows in multiple spaces, in which case they'll all open on the assigned space.